# Redirect all visitors without SSL except one IP

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect all visitors on my site (example.com) to the SSL version of the site except for 1 server IP address, using htaccess. I cannot seem to get it working... both separate do work but ssl **and** ip exception gives me headache.

Something as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} != 124.125.126.127 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L,QSA]
```

*(i've searched but this combo ssl & exception not found)*

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `[OR]`, just need both conditions anding together:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^124\.125\.126\.127$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: see updated one. If you still get 500 then do check your Apache error.log to see what the error is.

Comment: Now I do not get an error anymore, but the rewritecond https doesnt work anymore (nothing is redirected)

Comment: Only if request is from `124.125.126.127` then `https` redirect won't be in effect. For all other IP redirect should work.

Comment: Make sure this rule is placed just below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: yeah I know but when I change the IP to 95.96.97.98 I still do not get redirected. And `RewriteEngine On` is in the htaccess file.

Comment: The thing is `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^124\.125\.126\.127$` will only disallow the rule when IP is `124.125.126.127` If there are more rules show them in question and also tell me what Apache version are you running?